# Problem "$gte" : "?" in production on MongoDb with NodeJs

Tags: node.js, typescript, mongodb, mongoose, typeorm

I have a problem with an execution difference between QA and Production environment using Node + (Mongoose or TypeOrm) + MongoDb.

The problem occurs when using the "$gte" function which works in QA environment and returns records, but in production environment it doesn't.

During the analysis I was able to identify that apparently MongoDb is not able to identify the date value in production, because in the query filter it is like this **"$gte" : "?"**

The problem is that this only happens in production. And the environment in theory is equalized because we use container docker between environments and the Mongo version is equivalent too.

The only detail I was able to identify is the -03:00 difference contained in the production record, but I don't believe that's it:

**QA:** createdAt: ISODate("2021-06-28T13:46:24.612Z") 
**PRODUCTION:** createdAt: ISODate("2021-06-29T12:20:32.554-03:00")

Below, the MongoDb version, the code, the Grafana log and the logs of the query executed in MongoDb in each environment:

MogoDb version production: 4.2.3 
MogoDb version qa: 4.2.3

```js
  public async getReturnFiles(user: IUserToken): Promise<Orders[]> {
    const filter = {
      customId: user.customId,
      createdAt: {
        $gte: moment().subtract(5, 'days').startOf('day').toDate(),
      },
      returnFile: { $ne: null },
    };
    logger.info(`OrderService::getReturnFiles::filter::`, filter);
    return this.ordersModel
      .find(filter)
      .sort({ createdAt: 'DESC' })
      .select(this.keys.join(' '))
      .exec();
  }
```

**Grafana log (production and qa is the same thing)**

```js
OrderService::getReturnFiles::filter:: {"select":["createdAt","_id","returnFile"],"order":{"createdAt":"DESC"},"where":{"customId":"37296592000140_FOO","orderStatus":"Executed","createdAt":{"$gte":"2021-06-27T00:00:00.000Z"}}}
```

**Query executed in QA**

```js
{
    "op" : "query",
    "ns" : "foo.orders",
    "command" : {
        "find" : "orders",
        "filter" : {
            "customId" : "55029848000135_FOO",
            "orderStatus" : "Executed",
            "createdAt" : {
                "$gte" : ISODate("2021-06-25T00:00:00Z")
            }
    }
     }
}
```

**Query executed in PRODUCTION**

```js
{
    "op" : "query",
    "ns" : "foo.orders",
    "command" : {
        "find" : "orders",
        "filter" : {
            "customId" : "37296592000140_FOO",
            "orderStatus" : "Executed",
            "createdAt" : {
                "$gte" : "?"
            }
        }
     }
}
```

Comment: I tested it with Mongoose and also tested it with TypeOrm but without success.

Comment: `moment().subtract(5, 'days').startOf('day').toDate()` is 4 separate function calls.  Try breaking down that line and log each component, i.e. log `moment()` and `moment().subract(5,'days')`, etc, and see where exactly that changes from being a date to a '?'

Comment: I am not sure but I think the problem here is related to moment ```.toDate()``` function. So instead of using moment.toDate(), you can try using javaScript date method.
```new Date(moment().subtract(5, 'days').startOf('day'))```